# Generate IL to decrease counter in for loop

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, code-generation, cil, reflection.emit

I am hacking around with the Good For Nothing (GFN) compiler, trying to make it do a few different things. I am using the code from here: https://github.com/johandanforth/good-for-nothing-compiler

Regular GFN for loop:

```
var x = 0;
for x = 0 to 3 do
    print x;
end;
```

This for loop always increments. I'd like to add decrement functionality:

```
var x = 0;
for x = 3 to 0 down //up for increment (works same as do)
    print x;
end;
```

The main area I am struggling with is the CodeGen.

ForLoop class:

```
public class ForLoop : Stmt
{
    public Stmt Body { get; set; }
    public Expr From { get; set; }
    public string Ident { get; set; }
    public Expr To { get; set; }
    public ArithOp Type { get; set; }
}
```

ArithOp enum:

```
public enum ArithOp
{
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
    Up,
    Down
}
```

Inside CodeGen.cs:

```
private void GenStmt(Stmt stmt)
{
   //code omitted for brevity 

    else if (stmt is ForLoop)
            {
                // example: 
                // for x = 0 to 100 up
                //    "hello";
                // end;

                // x = 0
                var forLoop = (ForLoop)stmt;
                var assign = new Assign { Ident = forLoop.Ident, Expr = forLoop.From };
                GenStmt(assign);
                // jump to the test
                var test = _il.DefineLabel();
                _il.Emit(OpCodes.Br, test);

                // statements in the body of the for loop
                var body = _il.DefineLabel();
                _il.MarkLabel(body);
                GenStmt(forLoop.Body);

                // to (increment/decrement the value of x)
                _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, SymbolTable[forLoop.Ident]);
                _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
                _il.Emit(forLoop.Type == ArithOp.Up ? OpCodes.Add : OpCodes.Sub);
                GenerateStoreFromStack(forLoop.Ident, typeof(int));

                // **test** does x equal 100? (do the test)
                _il.MarkLabel(test);
                _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, SymbolTable[forLoop.Ident]);
                GenerateLoadToStackForExpr(forLoop.To, typeof(int));
                _il.Emit(OpCodes.Blt, body);
            }
}

private void GenerateStoreFromStack(string name, Type type)
    {
        if (!SymbolTable.ContainsKey(name))
            throw new Exception("undeclared variable '" + name + "'");

        var locb = SymbolTable[name];
        var localType = locb.LocalType;

        if (localType != type)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("'{0}' is of type {1} but attempted to store value of type {2}", name,
                localType == null ? "<unknown>" : localType.Name, type.Name));

        _il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, SymbolTable[name]);
    }

    private void GenerateLoadToStackForExpr(Expr expr, Type expectedType)
    {
        Type deliveredType;

        if (expr is StringLiteral)
        {
            deliveredType = typeof(string);
            _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, ((StringLiteral)expr).Value);
        }
        else if (expr is IntLiteral)
        {
            deliveredType = typeof(int);
            _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, ((IntLiteral)expr).Value);
        }
        else if (expr is Variable)
        {
            var ident = ((Variable)expr).Ident;
            deliveredType = expr.GetType();

            if (!SymbolTable.ContainsKey(ident))
            {
                throw new Exception("undeclared variable '" + ident + "'");
            }

            _il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, SymbolTable[ident]);
        }
        else if (expr is ArithExpr)
        {
            var arithExpr = (ArithExpr)expr;
            var left = arithExpr.Left;
            var right = arithExpr.Right;
            deliveredType = expr.GetType();

            GenerateLoadToStackForExpr(left, expectedType);
            GenerateLoadToStackForExpr(right, expectedType);
            switch (arithExpr.Op)
            {
                case ArithOp.Add:
                    _il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
                    break;
                case ArithOp.Sub:
                    _il.Emit(OpCodes.Sub);
                    break;
                case ArithOp.Mul:
                    _il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
                    break;
                case ArithOp.Div:
                    _il.Emit(OpCodes.Div);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Don't know how to generate il load code for " + arithExpr.Op +
                                                      " yet!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("don't know how to generate " + expr.GetType().Name);
        }

        if (deliveredType == expectedType) return;

        if (deliveredType != typeof (int) || expectedType != typeof (string))
            throw new Exception("can't coerce a " + deliveredType.Name + " to a " + expectedType.Name);

        _il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof (int));
        _il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof (object).GetMethod("ToString"));
    }
```

This currently generates an .exe that does nothing. Sources I have looked at to help solve this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3778/Introduction-to-IL-Assembly-Language#Loop and https://ninjaferret.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/msil-4-for-loops/. I just don't know enough IL

Comment: This looks like `for i = 0 to 3 do` runs three times, for `i = 0`, for `i = 1` and for `i = 2`. Is that correct, or does it actually run four times? If it is correct, what are you expecting for the `down` version to do? Should it run for `i = 3`, `i = 2`, `i = 1`, or should it run for `i = 2`, `i = 1`, `i = 0`?

Comment: @hvd it runs three times so `0 1 2` is the output for `up` (same as `do`). For `down` I'd like it to output `3 2 1`

Comment: @HansPassant does that mean for `down` I'll need to go with OpCodes.Bgt? I did give it a try, but the generated .exe still outputs nothing

Comment: @HansPassant ignore that last comment. I had an error in my code, OpCodes.Bgt works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in C# code to get insight:

```
   for (int ix = 0; ix < 3; ++ix)     // up
   for (int ix = 3; ix > 0; --ix)     // down
```

There are *two* changes, you got the difference in the inc/dec operator.  You didn't get the change in the loop termination condition.  Which makes this the bug:

```
   _il.Emit(OpCodes.Blt, body);
```

You'll have to invert that to Opcodes.Bgt